# Does the Selenium clickAt command work with headless browsers?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs, webautomation

I'm considering to replace Firefox with a headless browser such as `PhantomJS` (or `htmlunit`) for web scraping activities with `selenium`.

I think the `clickAt` command in selenium depends on page graphic rendering, and it won't work in `PhantomJS`. Can anybody confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (in Python 3.5):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':       
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('<YourPathtoPhantom>')    
    driver.set_window_size(1400, 1000)
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    el = driver.find_element_by_name('btnI')

    action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(el, 5, 5)
    action.click()
    action.perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
```